# Which is the best model for explaining spatial distance between points?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, geostatistics

I have a dataset with distances between beneficiaries and the nearest provision point (nearest hub).

I want to develop a model to explain distances based on several atrributes like category of beneficiary, category of provision point among others:

distance ~ cat_beneficiary + cat_provision + altitude + ...

I guess I should use a GLM, but I don't know which model would fits better with this kind of data (continuos and positive). Can I use a count data model (like Poisson or NB)? Or they just work with discrete data?

I attach a histogram.

[image: histogram of distance]

Thank you.

Comment: Three points to make: 1) Why do you want to treat this different just because it’s distance? (I’m not saying you’re wrong, but it will help you know your rationale.) 2) The typical assumption in linear regression about normality applies to the errors (residuals, empirically), not to the pooled distribution of all observations of the response variable. 3) The assumption of a normal error term helps us do parameter inference, but the Gauss-Markov theorem makes no such assumption about a normal error, so we get the unbiased estimator even if the error is not normal.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm a self-learner on statistic, so I don't have the theory behind. I know, for instance, that if data is positive and discrete, I should use a GLM with Poisson distribution, but if the same data is overdispersed, I should use a Negative binomial distribution. So, I was wondering, what kind of distribution could fit better my data.

My aim is to check which variables explain better the distance value between a point and its nearest provision point.

I guess you are telling that I should try different models and test whose residuals fit better.

Comment: Multidimensional scaling is one approach to estimating distances that correspond (more or less) to geographic distances, e.g., see this link...https://personality-project.org/r/psych/help/cities.html

Answer (score 0):

After researching about that. I checked that a Gamma distribution is which fits better with my data. However, since must data contains 0 values, I must use a zero-inflated gamma distribution.

Answer (score -1):

Indirectly for distances, there is Principal Component Analysis (PCA) which looks to find a low-dimensional representation of the observations that explain a good fraction of the variance.

K-means clustering, meanwhile, searches for homogeneous subgroups among the observations. There is also hierarchical clustering.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I'm rather looking for a predictive model such as GLM.  Distance in my model is not distance among variables but actual distance in the real world since the data is geographic, I'm not sure if I was clear enough about that in my question. Best wishes!